# Nodejs - Upload image to mongo document, then retrieve it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, loopbackjs

I've been struggling for a While now. I want to upload an image to mongo, not GridFS, I want tu save the image in a document.

This is what I have so far:

To upload the image:

```
News.image = function (id, req, res, cb) {

    News.findById(id).then(function (news) {
      if (!news) return cb({name: 'Not Found', status: '404', message: 'No news was found with given Id'});
      if (!req.file) return cb({name: 'Bad Request', status: '400', message: 'No file was sent'});

      var data = req.file.toString('base64');
      app.models.Image.create({content: data, mimetype: req.file.mimetype}).then(function (img) {
        cb(null, news);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        cb(err);
      });

    });
  };
```

Then I get this in the database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ce4ae12f409cb685283a9f"), "mimetype" : "image/png", "content" : BinData(0,"W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd") }
```

This is the code I use to retrieve the image:

```
Image.data = function (id, res, cb) {
    Image.findById(id).then(function (img) {
      if (!img) {
        var err = new Error("Image not found");
        err.statusCode =  404;
        throw err;
      }

      var image = new Buffer(img.content, 'base64');
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
      res.end(image, 'binary');

    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      cb(err);
    });
  };
```

And this is what I get back in my browser:
[image]

I just don't know if I'm storing the file the way I need to or I'm not getting it from the database the right way. How can I make this work?